# Cannot open PDFKit generated file

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, pdfkit, node.js-fs

I want to create a pdf file in my NodeJs server and then stream to the client, so it can download it, but I am not able to open the pdf file.

I created a pdf file using PDFKit, using the code in the documentation:

```
const doc = new PDFDocument({});
doc.text("Test");

const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("MyTest.pdf");
writeStream.on("close", () => {
    console.log("done");
});
doc.pipe(writeStream);
doc.end();
```

The pdf file gets created, but when I try to open it 2 things can happen:

1. Adobe Acrobat does not open at all
2. Adobe Acrobat opens after serveral minutes

I have the same behaviour if I open the file with Google Chrome.

I already looked into previous StackOverflow questions, like:

1. [error while opening pdf file created by pdfkit in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433532/error-while-opening-pdf-file-created-by-pdfkit-in-node/51366829#51366829)
2. [PDFKit, Not able to open the pdf generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802587/pdfkit-not-able-to-open-the-pdf-generated)

But these solutions seem not working for me.

Any ideas on how I have to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, I was creating the file in Windows WSL and opening from WSL's fileSystem with Windows' Adobe Acrobat. This operation is very slow.

A quick workaround to see the result of the pdf operation is to copy the .pdf file to Windows' desktop and open it from there.